# The code I've seen on youtube aren't working. I need to do Rowfilter by using textchanged event on a text box

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

The code I've seen on youtube isn't working. I need to do Rowfilter using TextChanged event on a TextBox.
I am using MS ACCESS as my database.

```
DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;

dv.RowFilter = "Patient_Number LIKE '%" + textBox11.Text + "%'";
```

It says column not found.

Comment: You should elaborate a bit more your question in order to receive the best answer possible.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.rowfilter?view=netframework-4.8

To form a RowFilter value, specify the name of a column followed by an operator and a value to filter on. The value must be in quotation marks. For example: "LastName = 'Smith'"

I wrote up a little dummy Winforms app to test your code, and placed a textbox on the main form called textbox11, just like your example.

When running in debug mode, the code

`String test = "Patient_Number LIKE '%" + textBox11.Text + "%'";`

evaluates to: "Patient_Number LIKE '%1234%'", when I enter a value of 1234 into textbox11. This appears to be formatted correctly because when I remove the outer double quotes use the text as a WHERE condition in SQL, the query evaluates properly.

Based on this finding, my guess would be that the column Patient_Number does not exist in your DataView object.  To check this, put a break point on the line

```
DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
```

and look at the "Columns" property of your DataTable object (dt) in the Watch Window of Visual Studio.  For this code to work, your DataTable will need to contain the column you are trying to filter on, Patient_Number.